# Token mismatch exception even after adding protected $except array

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

Well, this is the third that this `token mismatch` is making me crazy. I tried adding the tokens as suggested by others on Stack Overflow but that did not solve the problem. Then I tried removing protection from certain routes, that is not working even. I don't know what's going on.
This is how I am removing `csrf protection`

```
protected $except = ['/donate-money', 'donate-money-main', '/donate-money-main'];
```

I have this in the head

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and following code before my AJAX request

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to pass the token in the header, but in the data you sent with the ajax request.

```
data: {_token: token, ......}
```

Removing the csrf protection is bad practice and you should avoid it.